# Laravel Eloquent With Tables that don't need timestamps()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've been searching for this answer in a few places, and I haven't found a solution.

One of my table a very simple two column table does not need created_at or updated_at fields. However, eloquent gives me an error because it attempts to add the two fields automatically.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `stimuli_tracker` (`session_id`, `stimulus`, `stimulus_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, cat, sample, 2015-11-14 16:49:16, 2015-11-14 16:49:16))
```

Laravel or Eloquent seems to be adding in these two fields but they obviously don't exist. How do I get Laravel/Eloquent to bypass this feature on this single table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the timestamps property on the model to false:

`public $timestamps = false;`

see the Timestamps section at: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: Thanks. Will give you the answer when the 6 minutes has elapsed.